# Why are "Path" Windows's environment variable and the command line different?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

On my Pc, running  Windows XP 5.1.2600, following

"My Computer" > "Properties" > "Advanced" > "Environment Variables" > "Path"

I get a string, but in a batch file, or directly typing from prompt, by means of

echo %path%

I get a different one.

Can someone, please, explain what makes them differ and how to fix the issue, setting the "DOS-path"  to the same value of "Windows-PATH" ?

Comment: Actually, in Windows, shouldn't you be getting *two* strings, one for the current user, and one for all users?

Comment: There is no "DOS" in Windows XP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of the `PATH` environment variable you see on the command line (which has nothing to do with "DOS" btw) is the sum of the system wide `PATH` variable and the user specific `PATH` variable.

If you open the dialog with the system variables from within the control panel, the upper part contains the user specific environment variables. The lower part contains the system variables.

If you set a `PATH` variable for your user to e.g. `c:\foo`, and the system path is be `c:\Windows\System32` then you'd see `c:\Windows\System32;c:\foo` when you do an `ECHO %PATH%` on the commandline.

Comment: Also their are volitile variables, CMD specific variables (like cmd ext version), and apppaths adds to the path. The path is also built from any path specified in autoexec.bat (it's done on a per user basis).

Comment: @Serenity: there is no `autoexec.bat` in Windows any more

Comment: >If any conflict exists between environment variables, Windows 2000 Professional resolves the conflict in this way: System environment variables are set first. 
User environment variables are set next and override conflicting system variables. Variables that are defined in Autoexec.bat are set last, but they do not override conflicting system or user environment variables. 
Note Path settings, unlike other environment variables, are cumulative. The full path ... is created by appending the path that is contained in Autoexec.bat to the paths in the System Properties sheet in Control Panel.

Comment: @Serenity: theoretically true, as documented in [KB124551](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/124551), but in practice it doesn't appear to work on modern versions of Windows - I've just tried it on my 32-bit Windows Vista machine.  Unless there's some trick to making it work, I think the documentation is out of date.

Comment: After a reboot the situation is unchanged and, provided that I understand rightly the point, none of the two variables is a substring of the other one. As example, **c:\myFoldA** is in system's PATH variable, and isn't seen on the command line; the opposite happens for **c:\myFoldB.**.

Answer (score 4):

Two things:

1. As others have mentioned, the full value of `PATH` is the combination of the user's `PATH` variable and the system's `PATH` variable.
2. If you change environment variables (including `PATH`), any processes already running (including the Command Prompt) will continue using the old environment variable values.  You will need to restart those processes to pick up any changes that you've made.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the difference you are seeing is that when a new process is made, its default environment contains a `PATH` variable that is made by merging the system variable with the user variable.

As for how to "fix the issue", there is nothing to fix. The system behaves as designed.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same issue where the System Variable that I get through the

> "My Computer" > "Properties" > "Advanced" > "Environment Variables" >
>   "Path"

was different that the one being displayed through the command line interface via

> ECHO %PATH%

The fix for this is basically to wait for the change to take place and this can be made faster by restarting the cmd and explorer. To do that you can simply end task for Explorer and CMD and then start a new task or restart it directly.

[image]

The same shall be done for the CMD as well.

Comment: I highly doubt that any amount of waiting will allow existing processes to pick up changes to environment variables.

Comment: It worked in my case so I thought probably it might be the case. Apparently the restart did the trick. Could it be?

Comment: Yes, you must restart the process to pick up changes to the environment.  Waiting by itself will not work.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows registry can hold path entries that do not show up in the Environment Variables version of PATH you see via the control panel.  (Why, I do not know).

The difference means that something (likely an install script) made changes to the registry.

To view or change the local user's path variable, look in the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment` key.

To view the system path, look in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`